# cakephp pagination: how to set a different 'page' parameter

Tags: cakephp, pagination

Is there any way to configure a different param for the current page number?

for example, I have this paginated url:

```
http://localhost/petproject/posts/index/page:2
```

And I would like to have the url like this:

```
http://localhost/petproject/posts/index/my_custom_page_param:2
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could simply [use the router](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html) to transform the URL into something else that matches your needs by adding a rewrite rule for that URL. Without researching it further I think this is the most easy solution.

Another one might be to check in `Controller::beforeFilter()` if your custom named arg is set and copy/set it to `params['named']['page']`.

Or extend the Paginator component and create your customized version of it.

Comment: I think the second option you listed is probably *easiest*. First solution might be overkill since everything would be matched. Third solution is probably the most "correct" way of doing it. All good options :)